# Images getting stacked over each other

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to work with bootstrap ui grid in my react project. I am making an image gallery. I have component like this

```
<div className="container">
                <ul className="row">
                    <li className="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"><img src={x}/></li>
                    <li className="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"><img src={x}/></li>
                    <li className="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"><img src={x}/></li>
                    <li className="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"><img src={x}/></li>
                    <li className="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"><img src={x}/></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

But the images are getting stacked over each other. Like this
[image]

Answer (score -1):

type "class" everywhere instead "classname"

Comment: or might you haven't add bootstrap.min.js or jquery in your webpage

Comment: It is reactjs. So className is what it follows. And I have bootstrap in my package.json file.